# Get name as String from a Javascript function reference?

Tags: javascript

I want to do the opposite of [Get JavaScript function-object from its name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773184/get-javascript-function-object-from-its-name-as-a-string)

That is, given:

```
function foo()
{}

function bar(callback)
{
  var name = ???; // how to get "foo" from callback?
}

bar(foo);
```

How do I get the name of the function behind a reference?

Comment: `var bat = foo; bar(bat)` - now what should it print?

Comment: @Alnitak. It should print `foo`. that's the function name. `bat` is a variable with a reference to the `foo` function.

Comment: what happens if the callback doesn't have a name? -- ie `bar(function() {...});`

Comment: @Spudley: ideally, the code should throw an exception stating that anonymous functions are not supported.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you can't use [`myFunction.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) then you can:

```
// Add a new method available on all function values
Function.prototype.getName = function(){
  // Find zero or more non-paren chars after the function start
  return /function ([^(]*)/.exec( this+"" )[1];
};
```

Or for modern browsers that don't support the `name` property (do they exist?) add it directly:

```
if (Function.prototype.name === undefined){
  // Add a custom property to all function values
  // that actually invokes a method to get the value
  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype,'name',{
    get:function(){
      return /function ([^(]*)/.exec( this+"" )[1];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, now I got it, the `(` if for the `exec` match, not a part of the regex. cool. +1. BTW, why it doesn't alert `foo)`?

Comment: Why it doesn't match `foo){...`?

Comment: @gdoron Because regex must match characters sequentially until it stops. The `function ` in the regex starts it matching, and then it consumes zero or more anything-but-a-( characters (as many as possible). Once it has done that, it must stop; it can't "skip over" non-matches and continue on.

Comment: This relies on `this` referring to the function object. That's not always the case though! foo.bar() -> `this` === foo for example.

Comment: modified a bit not to include spaces: /function ([^(\s]*)/

Answer (score 22):

```
var name = callback.name;
```

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name):

> The name property returns the name of a function, or an empty string for anonymous functions:

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pxmBt/1)

Comment: `[the name] property is not standard` is no longer true, it's in ECMA 6.0 / 2015: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-setfunctionname / Also see http://www.2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html

Answer (score 6):

```
function bar(callback){
    var name=callback.toString();
    var reg=/function ([^\(]*)/;
    return reg.exec(name)[1];
}

>>> function foo() { };
>>> bar(foo);
"foo"
>>> bar(function(){});
""
```

Comment: More elegant regex than mine; nice :) Are you certain that all browsers will place a space after the leading `function`?

Comment: @Phrogz I'm confident enough not to change the above. If there is an edge case, it would only affect the anonymous function anyway, and `bar` could easily be adjusted to take that into account.

Comment: Having seen your code I recall looking at the spec long ago for the normalized string representation and IIRC the space is required.

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = function fooBar(){};
console.log(x.name);
// "fooBar"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the object and function name with:

```
function getFunctionName()
{
    return (new Error()).stack.split('\n')[2].split(' ')[5];
}
```

For example:

```
function MyObject()
{
}

MyObject.prototype.hi = function hi()
{
    console.log(getFunctionName());
};

var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.hi(); // outputs "MyObject.hi"
```

Comment: This will probably work, but isn't it much more expensive to construct a stack-trace than to parse `this.toString()`?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm only using this for debug messages. The above answers would only return "hi" this returns "MyObject.hi".

Comment: That is really nice for debugging. Thanks or sharing!

Answer (score 1):

try to access the `.name` property:

```
callback.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking for the function on an specific object event, this may help:

```
var a = document.form1
a.onsubmit.name
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, with just a little modification (adding \ before parent), this work:

```
if (Function.prototype.name === undefined){
  // Add a custom property to all function values
  // that actually invokes a method to get the value
  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype,'name',{
    get:function(){
      return /function ([^\(]*)/.exec( this+"" )[1];
    }
  });
}
```