# Get the name of a prototype constructor inside the constructor itself in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the name of a class inside the class itself in javascript? It would be useful for recursions on dynamically created classes in my middleware.
Think that was an very improperly post — so I better define the problem I want to solve:

```
MyClass = function(){
  this.classname = ??? // Here is required and needed to store as a property
}

MyClass.prototype.log = function(){
   alert(this.classname); // The alert should be MyClass
}


var myClassObj = new MyClass();
myClassObj.log();
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes.

Comment: @alex23: https://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2013/02/prototypes.md

Comment: You can call it classes or not. JavaScript does NOT have that keyword (although it is reserved) but you can get the same functionality as in Java classes with prototypes. It is much less confusing for OOP people to say "class" than "objects linked to the same prototype object".

Comment: @PavelS.: Actually it is root of all evil: trying to rape javascript into your favorite class-based OOP language is pushing cubes through circles: you will get incomprehensible framework which emulates classes to some extent, but you can do stuff much better if you accept javascript native model, which move context, can import members from multiple objects and other powerful stuff incompatible with class based language.

Comment: @JanTuroň I agree with that. However, it's sometimes easier to start with OOP principles and get familiar with prototypes step by step, than having whole new paradigm and not knowing where to start.

Comment: @PavelS. It is different paradigm: if Java, PHP or C# is your first language, forget the patterns and start over from scratch. It is like using procedural style in OOP - you get antipattern of anemic domain model. If you want to be good javascript programmer, forget classes.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for this:

```
function MyClass() {};
var myInstance = new MyClass();
console.log(myInstance.constructor.name === "MyClass");
// true
```

To have this working, you must declare the function as above, not using `MyClass = function(){}`. Then, [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) property of function is used, leveraging prototype chain (when querying `constructor` property).

If you need to access directly in the constructor, use the constructor reference as well:

```
function MyClass() { console.log(this.constructor.name === "MyClass"); };
var myInstance = new MyClass();
// true
```

This question deals with similar topic, it might be useful for you as well:
[Get name as String from a Javascript function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624057/get-name-as-string-from-a-javascript-function-reference)

Comment: Don't forget to mention that this is a non-standard property, and is not supported everywhere!!!

Comment: @PavelS. Im working in a constructor / prototype context and dont declare functions this way. How is it in my context?

Comment: Constructor context always points to the new created object (unless it's called as common function without `new`, which should be never). If you declare the same function in the prototype, it works in the exactly same way:
`MyClass.prototype.protF = function() { console.log(this.constructor.name); };`

Answer (score 1):

If "class" defined properly, class object has contructor property, which is a reference to class object.

```
function A() {
  alert(this instanceof this.constructor);
}
var a = new A();
```

you can inspect A.prototype in console by

```
console.dir(A.prototype)
```

command

Comment: do you know how it is on a prototype constructor as written (now better) above?