# Call javascript functions Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am generating dynamic javascript in which i create few functions for storing value

```
function get[dynamicname](){
    return "some value";
}
```

i want to call this method in another function to get the values of all functions i created

i have all the dynamicnames which i used to create the functions in the function which i am calling..

```
function getallfunctionvals(){
    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        var s="get";
        var ss="()";
        console.log(s+array[i]+ss);
    }
}
```

this is how i am calling the dynamically generated functions but in the console i am getting the function name as string not the value inside it

Comment: if the function is in global scope then you can use `eval(s+array[i]+ss)` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: But he shouldn't. Use a map of functions, don't define functions in the global scope.

Comment: Agree, `window[dynamic]` is **not** a solution, nor is `eval`. This looks like a common XY problem.

Comment: @dystroy can u tell how to use map of functions

Answer (score 1):

Hi look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773184/get-javascript-function-object-from-its-name-as-a-string) post.

*One of the answer*:

if you know that its a global function you can use:

```
var functPtr = window[func_name];
//functPtr()
```

Otherwise replace window with the parent object containing the function.

Answer (score 0):

if defined function is in gloabal scope, you can use

```
window[s+array[i]]()
```

So if you have a function like `getName`. what it will do it will call something like

```
window["getName"]();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use eval function. Eg.

```
            var s = eval("function get(){}; gat();");
```

Comment: eval function is evil

Answer (score 0):

first of all:

```
function get[dynamicname](){
return "some value";
}
```

will generate error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Since "[" is not allowed in javascript function name and variable.

But you can do this:

```
function getName () {console.log('Name')};
function getAge  () {console.log('Age')};
```

When you invoke the above functions, you can do this:

```
var s="get";
var thingToGet = "Name";
var ss="()";

eval(s + thingToGet + ss)
```

Did I answer your question?