# javascript - check function not available (name of function - string)

Tags: javascript

How to check if there is a function declared ? The function name is available in variable. Example:

```
var n = 'f1';
if (!functionExists(n)) {
    //execute code when function not available
}
```

Comment: maybe `typeof window[n] === 'function'`, will work for global functions only

Comment: @Tushar will only work for global function. Will never work with closure for example

Comment: I guess you could use (eval) but  be really cautionous when using it.

Comment: Silly me answering a duplicate question when I should have answered the original. So [now I have](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33611485/157247).

Comment: The mentioned SO answers are enough for me.