# How to check if a variable is defined if you have a string of it in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know if you want to check if a variable `a` is defined you can do this

```
if (typeof a !== 'undefined') {
    // the variable is defined
}
```

but what if you want to make a function out of it, like this

```
function checkDefined(name) {
    return typeof name !== 'undefined';
}
checkDefined("a");
```

this wouldn't work, but how can I get it to work if I have to pass a string version of the variable name?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot do that for local variables.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Any time you find yourself using variable variables, you should be using an object instead.

Comment: For global variables you can use `window[name]`

Comment: In my case, I only have a string of the variable name I want to check if defined or not.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info

Comment: return `eval("typeof " + name) !== 'undefined'`

Comment: @Barmar Should be noted that undefined is a valid value for a variable to hold, so window[name] could possibly return an undefined value which the variable stores. A try/catch would be most effective or .hasOwnProperty().

Comment: @omega Use an object instead. What do the variables represent; what do they have in common? Group variables logically into objects, then you can use `someObject.variable` or `someObject[variableName]` and check their existence with `someObject.hasOwnProperty(variableName)`. Or use [`Map`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: @Adriani6 Doesn't the original `typeof a != 'undefined'` suffer from the same problem?

Comment: @Barmar It does indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking in global scope(window):

```js
var a = 'test';
var b = function() {};

function checkDefined(name) {
    return typeof this[name] !== 'undefined';
}

console.log(checkDefined("a"));
console.log(checkDefined("b"));
console.log(checkDefined("c"));
```

If you want check if variable or function is declared in class object you should pass new context to checkDefined method:

```js
    function MyCustomClass() {
        this.c = 'test';
    }

    function checkDefined(name) {
        return typeof this[name] !== 'undefined';
    }

    // Create new object of type MyCustomClass
    var myCustomClassObject = new MyCustomClass();

    // In this way you can check if variable/function is defined in object
    console.log(checkDefined.apply(myCustomClassObject, ["a"]));
    console.log(checkDefined.apply(myCustomClassObject, ["b"]));
    console.log(checkDefined.apply(myCustomClassObject, ["c"]));
```

apply will call a function immediately letting you specify both the value of this and any arguments the function will receive

Comment: Can you explain your answer instead of just posting code? Why use `this` when the function isn't an object property?

Comment: `this` is needed for checking definitions in objects. If you call `this` in global scope then it's refered to window, if you call `this` in class object - in this case `MyCustomClass` - it refers to `MyCustomClass object context`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611485/2968762). I think you can try to return with **eval**:

```
function checkDefined(name) {
  return eval("typeof " + name) !== 'undefined';
}
```

**Example:**

```
var a = 1;

checkDefined("a") // true
checkDefined(a) // true
checkDefined("b") // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also pass on which object context you need to check if the variable is defined or not. If it's global pass the window object

```
function checkDefined(name, ref) {
    if(!ref) {
      ref = window;
    }
    return !!ref[name]
}


checkDefined("a"); //false if already not defined


var obj = { a: 1, b:2};
checkDefined("a",obj);//true
```

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are properties of the currently scoped `this` object.

```js
const log = output => document.querySelector('pre')
  .innerText += output + '\n'
  

/* In this example, running in the browser, `this` points to `window`, but 
   in other environments would still point to whatever is the global object.
   Bind `this` to the ``checkDefined` so to ensure it keeps the same value
   as where you are calling from. */

const checkDefined = function chkDef(v) {
  return typeof this[v] !== 'undefined'
}.bind(this)

a = 5

log(checkDefined('a'))
log(checkDefined('b'))

/* This is the same basic idea, but we make it a little more portable by
   not binding until right before we use it, so `this` has the correct
   scope. */


unboundCheckDefined = function chkDef(v) {
  return typeof this[v] !== 'undefined'
}
newScope()

function newScope() {
  c = 5
  const checkDefined = 
    unboundCheckDefined.bind(this)
    
  log(checkDefined('a'))
  log(checkDefined('b'))
  log(checkDefined('c'))
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```